# cobertura-maven-plugin 2.6 hosted anywhere?

Tags: java, maven, cobertura

I've been eagerly awaiting cobertura-maven-plugin 2.6 and all the usage doco says it's the one to use: http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html however I can't see it on maven central.

Does anyone know if the maven artefacts for 2.6 are hosted anywhere else that we can point to? Or is it just that the site has been updated prematurely?

**Edit**
You can follow the activity here: https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues?milestone=3&state=open

The latest vote is here: http://mojo.10943.n7.nabble.com/VOTE-Release-MCOBERTURA-version-2-6-td40895.html

**Edit2**
2.6 has been released to maven central. Here it is ... in all its Glory :-)  ... http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.mojo%7Ccobertura-maven-plugin%7C2.6%7Cmaven-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time votes for a new release succeed, but not this time. I've reverted the documentation back to the latest released version.

Comment: Thanks for clarification - I thought I was going crazy ;-)

Comment: Notice that as per the second edit in Matt Byrne's OP, the issues with 2.6 have been resolved and it's now available.

Answer (score 3):

The release of 2.6 was abandoned after problems were identified in staging (http://mojo.10943.n7.nabble.com/Cobertura-2-0-2-w-Maven-Plugin-td40618.html#a40635). The site has been updated prematurely.